# Exception generated on multi band blending of two images

Tags: registration, blending

I am doing multi view occlusion image registration. I have applied SURF for finding and matching of feature. Using homography transformation, I generated perspective transformed image of reference image. I have also applied linear blending and additive weighted blending to generate final registered image. But I did not get good result. So, I am applying "Multi band blending" in openCV library using C++. 
My code are written as:

```
// Apply Multi Band Blender for overlaying of two images
    detail::MultiBandBlender blender;
//Blender::MultiBandBlender blender; 
    try{
    Rect bounding_box;
    Rect dst_roi;

    cout << "Before blend preparing" << endl;
    blender.prepare(dst_roi);

    cout << "After blend preparing" << endl;
    Mat mask, bigImage, curImage;
    //  warpPerspective(image3, perImg1, H, cv::Size(image3.cols,     image3.rows));
    warpPerspective(image3, curImage, perImg1, bounding_box.size());
    //Mat makeMask(Size sz, vector<Point2f> imageCorners, Mat homorgaphy)
    mask = makeMask(curImage.size(), scene, curImage);
    blender.feed(curImage.clone(), mask, Point(0, 0));
    blender.blend(bigImage, mask);
    bigImage.convertTo(bigImage, (bigImage.type() / 8) * 8);
    imshow("Result", bigImage);
    imwrite("Multi_Band_Register.jpg", bigImage);
    }
    catch (Exception e){ cout << "Exception is generated" << endl; }
```

During running program, I got exception error in

```
 blender.prepare(dst_roi);
```

Can you please help me to resolve this error?

Thank you,